# why does my program output "nan" instead of doubles (velocity and position?)

Tags: c, double, nan

I want this program to output values for the velocity and position, but it just outputs `NaN`. I have checked all my functions and I am not dividing by zero anywhere, what else could it be? The position and velocity are supposed to simulate an orbit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double kx1 (double vx);
double ky1 (double vy);

double kvx1(double G, double M, double x, double y);
double kvy1(double G, double M, double x, double y);

double kx2(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vx);
double ky2(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vy);

double kvx2(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vx);
double kvy2(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vy);

double kx3(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vx);
double ky3(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vy);

double kvx3(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vx);
double kvy3(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vy);

double kx4(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vx);
double ky4(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vy);

double kvx4(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vx);
double kvy4(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vy);

int main()
{

    double M,G,y0,vx,vy,x,y,h,t, positionx,positiony,velocityx,velocityy;
    G=6.67*pow(10,-11);
    h=10;
    t=0;
    M=5.97*pow(10,24);
    y=0;
    //y0=0;
    x=1738*pow(10,3);
    vx=0;
    vy=1.023*pow(10,3);

    FILE *fp, *fopen();
    fp=fopen("Orbit", "w");
    for (t=0; t<=1000; t++)
    {

        printf("%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf\n", y,x,vx,vy,t);
        fprintf(fp,"%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf,%lf\n", y,x,vx,vy,t);

        positionx=x+(h/(double)6)*(kx1(vx)+2*kx2(G,M,h,x,y,vx)+2*kx3(G,M,h,x,y,vx)+kx4(G,M,h,x,y,vx));
        positiony=y+(h/(double)6)*(ky1(vy)+2*ky2(G,M,h,x,y,vy)+2*ky3(G,M,h,x,y,vy)+ky4(G,M,h,x,y,vy));
        velocityx=vx+(h/(double)6)*(kvx1(G,M,x,y)+2*kvx2(G,M,h,x,y,vx)+2*kvx3(G,M,h,x,y,vx)+kvx4(G,M,h,x,y,vx));
        velocityy=vy+(h/(double)6)*(kvy1(G,M,x,y)+2*kvy2(G,M,h,x,y,vy)+2*kvy3(G,M,h,x,y,vy)+kvy4(G,M,h,x,y,vy));

            /*if (positiony==y0)
            {
                break;
            }*/

        x=positionx;
        y=positiony;
        vx=velocityx;
        vy=velocityy;

    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;

}

double kx1 (double vx)
{
double kx1ans;
kx1ans=vx;
return kx1ans;
}

double ky1 (double vy)
{
double ky1ans;
ky1ans=vy;
return ky1ans;
}

double kvx1(double G, double M, double x, double y)
{
double kvx1ans;
kvx1ans=(-1*G*M*x)/(pow((pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)),1.5));
return kvx1ans;
}

double kvy1(double G, double M, double x, double y)
{
double kvy1ans;
kvy1ans=(-1*G*M*y)/(pow((pow(y,2)+pow(y,2)),1.5));
return kvy1ans;
}

double kx2(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vx)
{
double kx2ans;
kx2ans=vx+(h*kvx1(G,M,x,y))/2;
return kx2ans;
}

double ky2(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vy)
{
double ky2ans;
ky2ans=vy+(h*kvy1(G,M,x,y))/2;
return ky2ans;
}

double kvx2(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vx)
{
double kvx2ans;
kvx2ans=(-1*G*M*(x+(h*kx1(vx))/2))/(pow((pow((x+(h*kx1(vx))),2)+pow(y,2)),1.5));
return kvx2ans;
}

double kvy2(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vy)
{
double kvy2ans;
kvy2ans=(-G*M*(y+(h*ky1(vy))/2))/(pow((pow((y+(h*ky1(vy))),2)+pow(x,2)),1.5));
return kvy2ans;
}

double kx3(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vx)
{
double kx3ans;
kx3ans=vx+(h*kvx2(G,M,h,x,y,vx))/2;
return kx3ans;
}

double ky3(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vy)
{
double ky3ans;
ky3ans=vy+(h*kvy2(G,M,h,x,y,vy))/2;
return ky3ans;
}

double kvx3(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vx)
{
double kvx3ans;
kvx3ans=(-G*M*(x+(h*kx2(G,M,h,x,y,vx)/2)))/(pow((pow((x+(h*kx2(G,M,h,x,y,vx))),2)+pow(y,2)),1.5));
return kvx3ans;
}

double kvy3(double G, double M, double x, double y, double h, double vy)
{
double kvy3ans;
kvy3ans=(-G*M*(y+(h*ky2(G,M,h,x,y,vy))/2))/(pow((pow((y+(h*ky2(G,M,h,x,y,vy))),2)+pow(x,2)),1.5));
return kvy3ans;
}

double kx4(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vx)
{
double kx4ans;
kx4ans=vx+(h*kvx3(G,M,h,x,y,vx));
return kx4ans;
}

double ky4(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vy)
{
double ky4ans;
ky4ans=vy+(h*kvy3(G,M,h,x,y,vy));
return ky4ans;
}

double kvx4(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vx)
{
double kvx4ans;
kvx4ans=(-G*M*(x+(h*kx3(G,M,h,x,y,vx))/2))/(pow((pow((x+(h*kx3(G,M,h,x,y,vx))),2)+pow(y,2)),1.5));
return kvx4ans;
}

double kvy4(double G, double M, double h, double x, double y, double vy)
{
double kvy4ans;
kvy4ans=(-G*M*(y+(h*ky3(G,M,h,x,y,vy))/2))/(pow((pow((y+(h*ky3(G,M,h,x,y,vy))),2)+pow(x,2)),1.5));
return kvy4ans;
}
```

Comment: What are the kvy1 etc functions?

Comment: I suggest you write `6.0` instead of `(double)6`.

Comment: `FILE *fp, *fopen();` really???? You didn't include the standard headers??? `printf()` (and all functions with variable number of arguments) **absolutely needs** a **correct prototype**!

Comment: @pmg, agreed stylistically about the 6.0, but it's not the issue

Comment: Could be prototypes, but to the OP: Is the first line of the file OK? (where the values are all the initialised ones). If not, then @pmg is probably correct.

Comment: you need to show the functions

Comment: Writing `6.0` is also not necessary. Plain `6` will do, as the other operand `h` is declared as a double.

Comment: Put the whole code up now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can write `6.67*pow(10,-11)` as `6.67e-11`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `y=0` and `vx=0`. It is possible that you are dividing 0 by 0 which is defined as a `NaN`. You need to look at the functions, like `kvx2(G,M,h,x,y,vx)`.

More [info on what can cause Non a Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Operations_generating_NaN)

**edit:**

You are calling

```
double kvy1(double G, double M, double x, double y)
{
  double kvy1ans;
  kvy1ans=(-1*G*M*y)/(pow((pow(y,2)+pow(y,2)),1.5));
  return kvy1ans;
}
```

with y being 0. `(pow((pow(y,2)+pow(y,2)),1.5)) = 0`, and obviously `G*M*y= 0`. Which lead to the situation described above. I didn't check for further bugs since this one is enough.

You will experience this kind of bugs as long as you use such cryptic and confusing variables.

Comment: Here is the full program with functions.

Comment: I have checked in my functions, i don't think i am dividing by 0 anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your assignment to `positiony` to

```
    double tmp1 = y;
    double tmp2 = h/(double)6;
    double tmp3tmp1 = ky1(vy);
    double tmp3tmp2 = 2*ky2(G,M,h,x,y,vy);
    double tmp3tmp3 = 2*ky3(G,M,h,x,y,vy);
    double tmp3tmp4 = ky4(G,M,h,x,y,vy);
    double tmp3 = tmp3tmp1 + tmp3tmp2 + tmp3tmp3 + tmp3tmp4;
    positiony = tmp1 + tmp2 * tmp3;
    if (t < 2) {
        printf("tmp1 is %f\n", tmp1);
        printf("tmp2 is %f\n", tmp2);
        printf("tmp3tmp1 is %f\n", tmp3tmp1);
        printf("tmp3tmp2 is %f\n", tmp3tmp2);
        printf("tmp3tmp3 is %f\n", tmp3tmp3);
        printf("tmp3tmp4 is %f\n", tmp3tmp4);
        printf("tmp3 is %f\n", tmp3);
        printf("positiony is %f\n", positiony);
    }
```

and, when running the program I get

```
tmp1 is 0.000000
tmp2 is 1.666667
tmp3tmp1 is 1023.000000
tmp3tmp2 is nan
tmp3tmp3 is 2042.120516
tmp3tmp4 is -295.258623
tmp3 is nan
positiony is nan
nan,1731387.732835,-1324.550838,nan,1.000000
```

So I conclude something in `ky2()` is wrong ...

Comment: It runs properly now, in kvy1, one of the ys is supposed to be an x. Thanks.

Comment: Its not doing what i want it to, but the program is running! Its supposed to simulate an orbit, but its just a straight line